# Role of subscript operator in arrays

Tags: c#

We declare multi-dimension array in C# as

```
Datatype[,] <arrayname> = new Datatype[size,size];
```

I was just wondering what's the role of **subscript operator[,]** here. Can someone explain above syntax how it works exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Datatype[,] identifier;
```

delclares a two-dimensional array of `Datatype`. The general syntax is, for n dimensions you put n - 1 commas (`,`) between the square brackets. For example for a four-dimensional array, put three commas:

```
 Datatype[,,,] identifier;
```

When you instantiate the array you have to set the size of each dimension, e.g.:

```
int sizeDimOne = 5, sizeDimTwo = 10, sizeDimThree = 10;
Datatype[,,] identifier = new Datatype[sizeDimOne, sizeDimTwo, sizeDimThree];
```

Comment: Also they've given "a.GetLength(0)" to get no of rows
and                        "a.GetLength(1)" to get no of cols 

Is there any specific reason to use  0 for "row" 
and                                                  1 for "col"  ?????

Answer (score 1):

As part of a declaration, this part:

```
[,]
```

means "2-dimensional array", a rectangular array that will have 2 dimensions. You can call them "width" and "height" or whatever you wish, but 2 there is.

The number of commas denote the number of dimensions, minus 1, meaning that to declare a 3-dimensional array you would use 2 commas:

```
Datatype[,,] = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Object initialization in C# occurs in two step:

1)Create reference to the required type i.e int []num

2)Allocating physical memory of that object type i.e new num[2]

The subscript operator on the left-hand side gives an indication to the CLR that object that is currently being allocated to memory is fully compatible with the type of physical object that is being allocated memory.
For multidimensional array, each comma adds a dimension to array

For 1-D array []

2-D Array [,]

3-D Array[,,]